# BATCH: Convert output of dir /b to lowercase

Tags: batch-file

It seems the 'dir' command when used with /b option (bare format) doesn't recognize the /l (lowercase) option.
I'm trying to get the extension of files in a directory but I'm unable to strip the case, rendering the following code useless for all files with capitalized characters in their extensions.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /l /b/a-d /s') do (
if "%%~xa"==".iso" echo %%~xa
if "%%~xa"==".bin" echo %%~xa
)
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dir /l` certainly works for me, even in the combination of switches you gave there. But even if it didn't, there are two simple things:

1. Don't use `for /f` to iterate over `dir` output. It's error-prone and mangles Unicode characters unless you set your console options correctly. Use

   ```
   for /r %%a in (*) do ...
   ```

   instead, which will iterate over files recursively as well.
2. Use `/I` as an option to `if`:

   ```
   if /i "%%~xa" EQU ".iso" ...
   ```

And finally, why not take the easy route:

```
for /r %%a in (*.iso *.bin) do ...
```

This works regardless of case:

```
H:.
│   x
│
├───a
│       xyz.bin
│       xyz.ISO
│
└───b
        abc.BIN
        abc.iso

H:\Stuff>for /r %x in (*.iso *.bin) do @echo %x
H:\Stuff\a\xyz.ISO
H:\Stuff\a\xyz.bin
H:\Stuff\b\abc.iso
H:\Stuff\b\abc.BIN
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a toUpper function and call it on the %%~xa, then compare to .ISO or .BIN. [Here's](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Function.toUpper) a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Windows has powershell.  A one-liner in PS would be:  `ls * -recurse -include *.iso,*.bin`, which would ignore the case of the filenames.  (`ls` is an alias for `dir`)  [see comment by Joey]

Comment: You missed `-Recurse`. And `ls` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem` (as is `dir`).

Comment: @Joey: thanks, added the parameter.  the comment about ls being an alias to dir was an attempt to keep the terminology in the `batch` world for the OP.  Didn't want to start naming too many unfamilliar things for smeone coming from batch.